# Download NASA images to use as Windows wallpaper

Tags: javascript, http, windows, batch

I made myself a simple script (Batch/JScript) that download a pic from a blog (APOD) & set it as wallpaper.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

Set BaseUrl=https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/
set yr=%date:~8,2%
set mn=%date:~3,2%
set dy=%date:~0,2%
set dte=%yr%%mn%%dy%
set SaveDest=C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Wallpaper\%dte%.jpg
Set Url=%baseUrl%ap%dte%.html


@echo off
setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%Url%"') do (
    rem 
    echo %%I
    set LastImg=%%I
)

set ImgUrl=%BaseUrl%%LastImg:~6%
bitsadmin.exe /transfer GETWALLPAPER %ImgUrl% %SaveDest%
timeout /t 01
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d %savedest% /f
timeout /t 01
for /l %%x in (1,1,80) do  (
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d %savedest% /f
timeout /t 01
)

goto :EOF

JScript */
function fetch(url) {
    var xhr=WSH.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    var dom=WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile');
    xhr.open("GET",WSH.Arguments(0),true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
    xhr.send('');
    while (xhr.readyState!=4) {WSH.Sleep(25)};
    dom.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
    dom.write(xhr.responseText);
    return dom;
}
var dom=fetch(WSH.Arguments(0));
var link=dom.getElementsByTagName('IMG');

WSH.Echo(link[0].src);
```

It's working. However, I am unhappy about the `for /l %%x in (1,1,80) d` loop: it seems not to work without the loop. Any Idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***First :*** I recommend you to change this line in your code in order to anybody can use it easily without changing or editing it.

```
set SaveDest=C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Wallpaper\%dte%.jpg
```

by those lines :

```
set WallpaperFolder=%userprofile%\Desktop\Wallpaper
If not exist "%WallpaperFolder%" MD "%WallpaperFolder%"
set SaveDest=%WallpaperFolder%\%dte%.jpg
```

***Second :*** If you want to hide the output of the console you can redirect it to `NUL`

for example : `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d %savedest% /f>nul`

And this line too : `timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul`

***Third :*** Refer to [How to force Windows desktop background to update or refresh](https://superuser.com/questions/398605/how-to-force-windows-desktop-background-to-update-or-refresh?answertab=active#tab-top)

You can write it simply by this line and avoid the loop : `RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1, True`

So, the whole code can be written like this :

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*
@echo off
Title Download NASA images to use as Windows wallpaper
color 0A & Mode 70,3
Set BaseUrl=https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/
set yr=%date:~8,2%
set mn=%date:~3,2%
set dy=%date:~0,2%
set dte=%yr%%mn%%dy%
set WallpaperFolder=%userprofile%\Desktop\Wallpaper
If not exist "%WallpaperFolder%" MD "%WallpaperFolder%"
set SaveDest=%WallpaperFolder%\%dte%.jpg
Set Url=%baseUrl%ap%dte%.html

setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%Url%"') do (
    echo %%I
    set LastImg=%%I
)

set ImgUrl=%BaseUrl%%LastImg:~6%

bitsadmin.exe /transfer GETWALLPAPER "%ImgUrl%" "%SaveDest%"
echo(
echo        Please wait a while ... Update  UserSystemParameters 
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "%savedest%" /f>nul
Timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1, True
goto :EOF

JScript */
function fetch(url) {
    var xhr=WSH.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    var dom=WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile');
    xhr.open("GET",WSH.Arguments(0),true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
    xhr.send('');
    while (xhr.readyState!=4) {WSH.Sleep(25)};
    dom.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
    dom.write(xhr.responseText);
    return dom;
}
var dom=fetch(WSH.Arguments(0));
var link=dom.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
WSH.Echo(link[0].src);
```

Comment: Thank you. very instructive.

Comment: @a1a1a1a1a1 You can give a try for my vbscript version here [NASA_Wallpaper.vbs](https://pastebin.com/9QD2NfyQ)